# .NET webforms vs MVC for A Multi Step Student Data entry/edit form and A Visualization form using Google Visualization API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I would like to create a multi-step form for entry and editing of student data using .NET. What would be the right choice MVC or Webforms. Also i need to display reports based on user specified parameters using google visualization API. And what would be the better choice for the second task.

Thank you,
M

Comment: An idea of your experience in web tech may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a little bit subjective. My personal experience is that MVC was easier for me to get my head around, especially for being able to design my URL scheme, MVC routing tables I found to be very simple to grok.

Plus the tutorials available are great, Nerd Dinner is a wonderful tutorial and Stevn Sandersons book (pro asp.net MVC 2.0) is one of the better tutorial style manuals I have read.

Comment: I will try my first iteration with MVC. Thank you for the suggestions Tim